# Why does swift not compile when referring to protocol method directly?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Given the following struct:

```
struct TestStruct {
    func test() {
        print("Something")
    }
}
```

Referencing the `test` function like this works:

```
let testFunc = TestStruct.test // (TestStruct) -> () -> Void
```

In order to execute the function you would have to do the following:

```
testFunc(TestStruct())() // Prints "Something"
```

Say you make `TestStruct` conform to a protocol:

```
protocol Test {
    func test()
}

extension TestStruct: Test {}
```

Now trying to rather reference the `test` function through the protocol like this does not work:

```
let testFunc = Test.func // Does not compile, no error message
```

Shouldn't the type of `testFunc` be `(Test) -> () -> Void`? And why is it now compiling?

Comment: `Test.func` mistake?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski No, this is the actual question. Why can't I refer to that function of the protocol and pass it a class/struct implementing that protocol later?

Comment: I think @AdrianBobrowski is asking whether you meant to say `let testFunc = Test.test`, because the compiler does print an error message for what you wrote, which is `let testFunc = Test.func`.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks, @AdrianBobrowski yeah I meant to say `let testFunc = Test.test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you wrote is intended to work at some point, according to [SR-75](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-75). They haven't implemented it yet.

The fact that the compiler crashes instead of printing an error means that you have found a compiler bug.

```
:; xcrun swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.0 (swiftlang-900.0.54.10 clang-900.0.31). Type :help for assistance.
  1> struct TestStruct { 
  2.     func test() { 
  3.         print("Something") 
  4.     } 
  5. }
  6> protocol Test { 
  7.     func test() 
  8. } 
  9.  
 10. extension TestStruct: Test {}
 11> let testFunc = Test.test
Segmentation fault: 11
```

“Segmentation fault: 11” means the compiler crashed. <strike>You should go to https://bugs.swift.org/, create an account if you don't have one, and file a bug report.</strike>

You can see the compiler stack trace by putting the test code in a file and compiling it:

```
:; echo 'protocol Test { func test() }; let testFunc = Test.test' > main.swift && xcrun swiftc main.swift
0  swift                    0x000000010b5efeaa PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010b5ef2e6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9742fb3a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007f82e307de00 _sigtramp + 1271194336
4  swift                    0x0000000108818c2c swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::manageOpaqueValue(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::OpaqueValueState&, swift::SILLocation, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 188
5  swift                    0x000000010882fa1b swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 11067
6  swift                    0x000000010882d6a1 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 1985
7  swift                    0x0000000108838f01 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 49185
8  swift                    0x0000000108849329 void llvm::function_ref<void (swift::Expr*)>::callback_fn<swift::Lowering::RValue swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOpenExistentialExpr<swift::Lowering::RValue, (anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter::visitOpenExistentialExpr(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext)::$_5>(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, (anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter::visitOpenExistentialExpr(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext)::$_5)::'lambda'(swift::Expr*)>(long, swift::Expr*) + 41
9  swift                    0x00000001088499e7 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOpenExistentialExprImpl(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, llvm::function_ref<void (swift::Expr*)>) + 1591
10 swift                    0x000000010882e1cb swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 4843
11 swift                    0x000000010882cb74 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitExprInto(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::Initialization*) + 148
12 swift                    0x000000010881ccf6 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitPatternBinding(swift::PatternBindingDecl*, unsigned int) + 198
13 swift                    0x00000001087ce3cf swift::ASTVisitor<swift::Lowering::SILGenModule, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 559
14 swift                    0x00000001087cd4ab swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 1115
15 swift                    0x00000001087cee39 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool) + 841
16 swift                    0x0000000107f6dedc performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 13020
17 swift                    0x0000000107f69394 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7332
18 swift                    0x0000000107f1ead8 main + 12248
19 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff97220235 start + 1
20 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000000f start + 1759378907
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file main.swift -target x86_64-apple-macosx10.9 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -color-diagnostics -module-name main -o /var/folders/kn/1d839myx4tlghz34f_lh3hvc0000gn/T/main-65ce73.o 
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 11 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The bug appears even without the declaration of `TestStruct`. But anyway the statement in line 11 is not correct, because it refers to an implementation of a protocol's method, which doesn't exists.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether statement 11 is correct. The compiler should never crash. The crash is the reason why the asker sees “no error message”. If statement 11 is incorrect, the compiler should print an error message, not crash.

Comment: You're right though that `TestStruct` is not required to trigger the crash.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right. The REPL has never to crash. But your answer is not an answer of Justin's question. The compiler doesn't produce the error because of a bug. It produces the error due to an invalid statement.

Comment: @macmoonshine The original question was why does it not compile, and both your answer and Rob's answers the question from different points of views, I am going to log the bug and will let you know of the response :)

Comment: @JustinGuedes: Rob's answer describes a bug in the REPL which has nothing to do with the compiler and which has nothing to do with your problem. When Apple will fix the REPL bug, the compiler will still not be able to compile your program because it contains an invalid expression.

Comment: @macmoonshine fair enough, thanks for clarifying

Comment: @macmoonshine Yeah, that's just not true. The bug is in the compiler. Put the test code in `main.swift` and run `swiftc main.swift` to see the stack trace.

Comment: @robmayoff: Yes, even it's a compiler bug, it's an invalid expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your struct and your protocol is that the protocol does not implement a method `test`. It just declares a method named `test`. The expression `TestStruct.test` returns a reference to the implementation of the method `test` of the struct. Because the protocol has no implementation for `test`, the compiler can't return a reference to this.

Note: The protocol `Test` does not *know* anything about its implementing classes or structs. Thus, `Test.test` cannot return the reference to `TestStruct.test`. In the case of multiple implementations of `Test` this would be ambigious, too.

Conclusion: You can't refer to method's implementation of protocols, because they have no implementation.

Comment: I get that, however its not directly referring to the implementation, it creates a function that takes in an implementation of `Test` and returns the functions implementation. It actually autocompletes if you were to just type `Test.` to the `test` function telling you that the type for that function is `(Test) -> () -> Void`

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly. You have to difference between the implementation and the type of `Test.test`. While it has the type `(Void) -> Void`, it has nevertheless an implementation.